# crear una clase para cargar una matriz de NxN en C#

Tags: c#, array

no se como declarar el atributo de la matriz sin dimensionarla, ya que la dimension se ingresaria por teclado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que se podría hacer es lo siguiente:

```
public int[,] cargarMatriz(input1, input2) {
    int[,] matriz = new int[input1, input2];
    return matriz;
}
```

una vez el usuario ingrese los datos, habría un botón que ejecute la función *cargarMatriz* y con esto quedaría resulto tu problema.

Saludos.

Comment: `return new int[input1, input2];`? Si, podría ser.

Comment: ah declarar la matriz dentro del metodo publico CargarMatriz decis vos? y por parametro el metodo recibiria la dimension? quiero chequear si te entendi nomas..

Comment: exacto esa es la idea. espero haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Usando estructuras estáticas, no es posible. Una solución podría ser conociendo los límites de las entradas a manejar, en ese caso crearías una matriz con las dimensiones de dichos limites, y solo manejarías las filas y columnas hasta las entradas que el usuario proporcione. El problema con esta solución es que puede desperdiciar una gran cantidad de memoria.

La otra solución es que utilices estructuras dinámicas. En C# existen varias que podrían adaptarse al comportamiento que necesitas, o bien realizar la tuya propia mediante nodos.

Comment: Gracias, justamente eso hago, sobredimensiono la estructura estatica y luego la pueblo con la dimension cargada por el usuario. Pero entiendo que desperdicio mucha memoria. En realidad es un ejercicio de programacion que nos dios el profesor, voy a chequear con el este tema. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada, pero no había pensando en el enfoque que propuso Arnold, y es la respuesta correcta a tu pregunta.